# Firebase: show children nodes in calendar

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to implement a calendar on my website which shows user submissions by their date on a calendar?

The following code captures some test variables and I would like them shown in the calendar by the date they were submitted.

```
function startDatabaseQueries() {
    alert("StartQueries");
    // Get current user info
    var myUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var username = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;
    // Get posts
        alert("1");

        var testRef = firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByKey();

        testRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
            var results = [];
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                //var key = childSnapshot.key;
                var childData = childSnapshot.val();
               // console.log(childData);
                var author = childSnapshot.val().author;
                console.log(childSnapshot);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = author;
            });
        });
}
```

The

```
console.log(childSnapshot)
```

shows the following code in the console: (Variable results omitted)

```
Author: 
AuthorPic:
submitted:
title:
uid:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend grabbing the date as well and store it on the database with the format "yyyyMMdd". Then, when you want to read the data, you would simply use:

```
var testRef = firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByChild("dateAdded");
```

Comment: I will certainly,use this advice thank you! Do you have any idea how I could display it on a calendar such as full calendar?